# Replacing a symbol with pipe in a string batch

Tags: batch-file, output

I have this string, call it str, which may look like this XinfoX. i want a command, using batch, which replaces the 'X's with this symbol '|' (a pipe symbol). i have tried this, but the cmd keeps closing/crashing.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried?

Comment: Presumably you are trying something like `set var=%var:X=|%`. You should show the code that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

use variable edit/replace see [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) for details

```
set str=XinfoX
echo %str:X=^|%

C:\>echo %str:X=^|%
|info|
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is crashing because the `|` character functions as the pipe operator. But you want to use it as a literal character instead. The character must either be escaped or quoted.

```
set str=XinfoY

:: using quotes
set "str=%str:X=|%"

:: using escape
set str=%str:Y=^|%
```

The situation can get complicated if your string contains quotes such that some of the string is quoted and some is not. The solution is to use delayed expansion.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set str="Xinfo1X"info2X
set "str=!str:X=|!"
```

Comment: None of this works for me. Works fine with dash instead of pipe. But if I use pipe, my command prompt always tries to execute instead of replace..